# Shiny-Server (AWS Ubuntu) Not rendering ShinyDashboard correctly

Tags: shiny-server, shinydashboard

Thank you for your help in advance.

I've setup shiny server on Ubuntu in Amazon Web Services. Everything is working correctly with other apps I've uploaded. However, I'm trying to use the package shinydashboards to create some dashboards. I'm running into an issue where the first submenu item is not being rendered.

You can see the app live in AWS here. https://www.ndperfsci.com/apps/TestApps/PerfSci_App/

It functions just fine in ShinyApps.io
https://webbphysprep.shinyapps.io/test/

Here is the exact code I'm using:

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')

# Sidebar #############################
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Catapult', tabName = 'menu_ctplt', icon = icon('circle-o'),
              collapsible =
                menuSubItem('Upload Files', tabName = 'submenu_ctplt_upload'),
                menuSubItem('Edit Records', tabName = 'submenu_ctplt_edit')
    )
  ),

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Force Decks', tabName = 'menu_fd', icon = icon('circle-o'),
            collapsible =
              menuSubItem('Upload Files', tabName = 'submenu_fd_upload'),
              menuSubItem('Edit Records', tabName = 'submenu_fd_edit')
    )
  )

)

# Body #############################
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'submenu_ctplt_upload',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item One')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'submenu_ctplt_edit',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Two')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'submenu_fd_upload',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Three')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'submenu_fd_edit',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Four')
    )
  )
)

# UI #############################
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'ND Perf-Sci Apps'),
  skin = 'black',
  sidebar,
  body
)

# Server #############################
server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Bump, could someone please help?